# C# Back-end service to Yammer API using AAD Token

Tags: c#, bearer-token, yammer, yammer-api

I'm try to develop a back-end service to create new users and add them to a Yammer Group.

What is the C# code to acquire an access token and then call the Yammer API endpoints with (Authorization "Bearer ")?

As a backend service, the code expects to run without the user login page.

The Azure administrator just configured the app and he sent me the data below.

Data to access the Yammer API:
[image: data to access the Yammer API]